# Listing an empty folder shows two items . and .. , what are they?

Tags: filesystem, files, file-sharing, filemanager, file-format

When I make a folder `test` and `cd` into it, it's empty.

However, running `ls -la` returns:

```
total 8>
drwxrwxr-x  2 algosig algosig 4096 august  15 23:09.
drwxr-xr-x 41 algosig algosig 4096 august  15 23:09.
```

What do the single and double points (`.` and `..`, respectively) mean? Also, what does the `total 8` line mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` refers to the current location, and `..` refers to the parent directory.

The 8 is 8K. Try using `ls -alh`.

Comment: what is 8K, is it . and .. are of 8 byte?

Comment: 8K is 8 kilobytes.  To find the size of . and .., just `sudo du -sk .`

Comment: In the middle of each line of `ls` output, there is a `4096`, indicating that `.` and `..` are 4096 bytes each, so the total is 8192.

Answer (score 2):

In order, '.' is the current directory, and '..' is the parent of the current directory.  typing `cd ..` will move you up the directory tree one level.